# Android keyboard changes height

Tags: android, css

I am building an app with HTML/CSS/JavaScript for the android. Now I have add a simple inlog field (for the purpose of the question I added a couple more fields).

[no keyboard](http://i50.tinypic.com/kbsk5f.png)

When I want to fill in the form I just focus on the field and my onscreen keyboards of android gets added to the screen.

So far so good, but when I want to scroll to the submit button there is a problem. As you could have seen in the first picture there was a "nice" submit button, and when I want to scroll I can't reach it.

[the farest I could reach](http://i47.tinypic.com/244ek8z.png)

**Anser to question**

The problem seems to be fixed, after just "giving up" I looked into the AndroidManifast.xml and start messing around what everything ment.

```
<application android:icon ="@drawable/icon"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.FullScreen">
```

Since I just began I just started messing arround, and foud the problem lay with the androud:theme.

After removing it, you will get your webpage into a wrapper, to fix this use

```
<application android:icon ="@drawable/icon"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
```

Using this solves the problem, except this also means that the status bar of android will be shown.